# PHP -- Output to a large text file is slow and may cause a server error

Tags: php, file, output

I have code that creates a text file that is around 6.8mb in file size. When I run the code on my local machine it is not fast, but it completes. When I run it on the server, it never seems to complete, and once I got a server error (did not write the actual error code down, but it was a rather vague error).

I am wondering if this might be a buffer issue? The code is opening the file once, issuing the fwrite() function calls in a loop to generate the output. Would it be better to write some information, close the file, re-open it in append mode, and write more data, then close it, re-open and so on? I am opening the file like this:

```
// need a file handle to write to it:
$file_handle = fopen( $outFile, 'w') or
        die('Cannot open file:  ' . $outFile ); //implicitly creates file
```

and using standard "fwrite()" calls:

```
// output this:
fwrite( $file_handle, $indent . $out . "\n" );
```

(where $out is a string built inside the loop to create the output, and $indent is just 5 spaces ...)

When done, the file gets closed:

```
fclose( $file_handle );
```

This is frustrating, as the code works perfectly in my local environment, but not on the server.

I'm just looking for advice, seeing if anyone else has run into an issue like this. Before I spend the time to break the code up and add closing and re-opening for append, etc., it would be useful to know that I'm not barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Keeping the file open is faster than reopening it.

Comment: timeout or triggering one of the other php limits, you need to debug this a little better make suer full error checking anf logging are on at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: 7 MB is not very large. Did you mean GB?

Comment: I am seeing in Windows Explorer 6.78KB which would mean 6.8MB, correct?

I understand keeping the file open is faster, but am wondering if that would resolve any issues with buffering or memory on the server.

Comment: Will take a look at the ini_set() and error_reporting() function calls. Thanks.

Comment: 6.78 kilobyte is 0.00678 Megabyte, so are you sure?

Comment: Sorry, too much running through my head. 6,759KB is what is showing in File Explorer (Windows 10).

Comment: Also, have code that updates the screen with script calls to JavaScript, which works well on my local environment, but on the server doesn't update much at all:

     // increment name counter:
     $names_done++;
     //set the width for the progress bar:
     $completed = ( $names_done / $total_rows ) * 100;
     echo "<script>document.getElementById('CurrentProgress').style.width='" . $completed . "%'</script>";

This is a Bootstrap progress bar, and again, it works locally pretty well, but on the server doesn't ... is there some setting to cause the server to interact better?